# C# Crystal Reports ConnectionInfo and Parameters

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a c# application that passes certain parameters to a Crystal report and then loads the report.  This is all working as expected, but I now have the requirement for the application to be run against a different database, other than the local database.

I have added the connection info for the report, but when loading the report it is now prompting for the report parameters.  If I run the same code (with the connection info in) against the local database it runs correctly (without the parameters prompt.  Here is my code:

```
        public frmReport(ReportDocument cryRpt, DateTime dFromDate, DateTime dToDate,
        Int32 iEmployeeId, Int32 iRetentionDays, 
        Boolean bExTax, Boolean bShowDefinitions, DBase _oDbase, Log _oLog)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _oDBase = _oDbase;

        iEmployeeIdReport = iEmployeeId;

        TableLogOnInfos crtablelogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        TableLogOnInfo crtablelogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        Tables CrTables;

        string sWowPath = Wow6432Path();

        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software" + sWowPath + "\\ShortCuts\\Database\\ShortcutsPOS").GetValue("Server").ToString(); ;
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software" + sWowPath + "\\ShortCuts\\Database\\ShortcutsPOS").GetValue("Database").ToString(); ;
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = Properties.Settings.Default.Username.ToString();
        crConnectionInfo.Password = Properties.Settings.Default.Password.ToString();

        CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;

        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
        {
            crtablelogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
            crtablelogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtablelogoninfo);
        }


        ParameterFields myParams = new ParameterFields();
        ParameterField paramFieldFrom = new ParameterField();
        ParameterField paramFieldTo = new ParameterField();
        ParameterField paramFieldEmployeeId = new ParameterField();
        ParameterField paramFieldRetentionDays = new ParameterField();
        ParameterField paramFieldExTax = new ParameterField();
        ParameterField paramFieldShowDefinitions = new ParameterField();

        ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValueFrom = new ParameterDiscreteValue();           
        ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValueTo = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteEmployeeId = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValueRetentionDays = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValueEmployeeLevelList = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValueExTax = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValueShowDefinitions = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

        paramFieldFrom.Name = "FromDate";
        paramFieldTo.Name = "ToDate";
        paramFieldEmployeeId.Name = "EmployeeId";
        paramFieldRetentionDays.Name = "RetentionDays";
        paramFieldExTax.Name = "ExTax";
        paramFieldShowDefinitions.Name = "ShowDefinitions";

        paramDiscreteValueFrom.Value = dFromDate;                       
        paramDiscreteValueTo.Value = dToDate;
        paramDiscreteEmployeeId.Value = iEmployeeId;
        paramDiscreteValueRetentionDays.Value = iRetentionDays;
        paramDiscreteValueExTax.Value = bExTax;
        paramDiscreteValueShowDefinitions.Value = bShowDefinitions;

        paramFieldFrom.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValueFrom);
        paramFieldTo.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValueTo);
        paramFieldEmployeeId.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteEmployeeId);
        paramFieldRetentionDays.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValueRetentionDays);
        paramFieldExTax.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValueExTax);
        paramFieldShowDefinitions.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValueShowDefinitions);

        myParams.Add(paramFieldFrom);
        myParams.Add(paramFieldTo);
        myParams.Add(paramFieldEmployeeId);
        myParams.Add(paramFieldRetentionDays);
        myParams.Add(paramFieldExTax);
        myParams.Add(paramFieldShowDefinitions);

        cryViewer.ParameterFieldInfo = myParams;

        cryViewer.Refresh();

        cryViewer.ReportSource = cryRpt;
    }
```

I'll add that the report location is passed to this method from another form, and then on the return of this the .Show() is run.

EDIT: Ok just ran some more tests and if my connection is machinename\dbinstance it also doesn't work, but it works with (local)\instancename.  The command object in the report file has a connection set of (local)\instancename, is this the problem?

Comment: Have you tried setting the parameters after setting the ReportSource? (e.g. `cryViewer.ParameterFieldInfo["FromDate"].Add(paramDiscreteValueFrom)`)

Comment: I have tracked this down to the sub report having its own command object.  The sub report didn't really need to be a sub report, so i have changed this and now i am good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sub report in this case had it's own command object, and this was the issue.  I have changed the report so the sub report no longer exists (was pretty basic and did't really need to be separate) and the issue stopped.